# SKPaymentQueue updatedTransactions method not being called after renewal

Tags: ios, swift, auto-renewable, skpaymenttransaction

I have implemented auto-renewable subscriptions in my app. All works ok. The only thing is that method `public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is not being called after auto-renewal occurs as it should according to docs to inform me that subscription was renewed. It is called only when I call `SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`

I know that it auto-renews only 5 times and than I have to create new sandbox user and I tried it few times.

In my `AppDelegate` I do call `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> After a subscription is successfully renewed, StoreKit adds a transaction for the renewal to the transaction queue. Your app checks the transaction queue on launch and handles the renewal the same way as any other transaction. **Note that if your app is already running when the subscription renews, the transaction observer is not called; your app finds out about the renewal the next time the app is launched.**

Source [In-App Purchase Programming Guide: Working with Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

What `transactionState` auto renewed transaction have, when `public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` is called? .purchased?